# Using awk, how to replace one string with another?

Tags: awk, gawk

Need to create an `awk` script to convert a `glyph` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) to `Unicode` (`JavaScript` syntax), and the reverse - Unicode to a glyph.

Source data is stored in `NotePad++` with `UTF-8` encoding.

Here's my progress.

**Use_case_1**

*Dictionary file* (dict_1_.txt):

```
A \u0041
À \u00C0
```

*Input file* (input_1_.txt):

```
A
À
```

`awk` script for generating Unicode for equivalent glyph:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } $1 in a { $1 = a[$1] } $2 in a { $2 = a[$2] } 1' dict_1_.txt input_1_.txt
```

correctly producing:

```
\u0041
\u00C0
```

**Use_case_2**

*Dictionary file* (dict_2_.txt)

```
\u0041 A
\u00C0 À
```

*Input file* (input_2_.txt)

```
\u0041
\u00C0
```

`awk` script for generating glyphs for equivalent Unicode:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } $1 in a { $1 = a[$1] } $2 in a { $2 = a[$2] } 1' dict_2.txt input_2.txt
```

correctly producing:

```
A
À
```

So, can successfully "round-trip" on a single symbol.

**But how to deal with a more comprehensive dictionary and more than one word per row?**

Here is sample data.

*Input file* (input_3_.txt)

```
PUDÍN, ALMIDÓN
```

*Dictionary file* (dict_3_.txt)

```
,   \u002C
A   \u0041
D   \u0044
I   \u0049
Í   \u00CD
L   \u004C
M   \u004D
N   \u006E
Ó   \u00D3
P   \u0050
U   \u0055
<space> \u0020
```

The `awk` script should generate:

```
\u0050\u0055\u0044\u00CD\u006E\u002C\u002C\u0041\u004C\u004D\u0049\u0044\u00D3\u006E
```

*Input file* (input_4_.txt)

```
\u0050\u0055\u0044\u00CD\u006E\u002C\u002C\u0041\u004C\u004D\u0049\u0044\u00D3\u006E
```

Dictionary file (dict_4_.txt)

```
\u002C  ,
\u0041  A
\u0044  D
\u0049  I
\u00CD  Í
\u004C  L
\u004D  M
\u006E  N
\u00D3  Ó
\u0050  P
\u0055  U
\u0020  <space>
```

The `awk` script should generate:

```
PUDÍN, ALMIDÓN
```

Here is a more complicated set of input strings (one per row):

```
MONO Y DIACETIL ÉSTERES DEL ÁCIDO TARTÁRICO DE MONO Y DIGLICÉRIDOS DE ÁCIDOS GRASOS AÑADIDOS
043 HUEVAS DE PESCADO (INCLUYENDO ESPERMA=HUEVAS BLANDAS) Y VÍSCERAS COMESTIBLES DE PESCADO
ACEITE DE SOJA OXIDADO TÉRMICAMENTE Y EN INTERACCIÓN CON MONO Y DIGLICÉRIDOS DE ÁCIDOS GRASOS
BANDEJA PLÁSTICA O CAZUELA, CUBIERTA DE PAPEL DE ALUMINIO O ENVOLTURA
```

In the Dictionary examples above, have used `<space>` to indicate the 'symbol' between words and after a comma. This probably means that a solution should use `\t` for `FS` in both the Dictionary file and the Input file. Currently the `FS` is a keyboard 'space'. Also the `RS` is `\n`.

Further, I need to do the same for hexadecimal, so a solution needs to process a Dictionary file like this:

```
Í   &#xcd;
Ó   &#xd3;
```

as compared to the Dictionary example above:

```
Í   \u00CD
Ó   \u00D3
```

**How to improve or replace my simple `awk` scripts with scripts that process the longer strings on multiple lines?**

Comment: wow. this question is way too long. How about shortening it?

Comment: The question is: `How to improve or replace my simple awk scripts with scripts that process the longer strings on multiple lines?`. The text shows progress (MCV) and data that hopefully can be processed by a proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one approach, note that you don't need two different versions of the dictionary.

With little effort these two can be combined into one script and from/to conversion can be controlled with a parameter.  I intentionally kept the dictionary part the same

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {$2=$2?$2:" "; u2a[$1]=$2; a2u[$2]=$1; next}
               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a2u[$i]}1' dict FS='' OFS='' input

\u0050\u0055\u0044\u00CD\u006E\u002C\u0020\u0041\u004C\u004D\u0049\u0044\u00D3\u006E
```

working with the encoded input now

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {$2=$2?$2:" "; u2a[$1]=$2; a2u[$2]=$1; next}
               {enc=$0; gsub(/....../,"& ",enc); n=split(enc,a);
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) line=line u2a[a[i]]; print line}' dict encoded_input

PUDÍN, ALMIDÓN
```

using your dict_4 as the dictionary for both scripts

Comment: Having problem with 'dict' in your text. Should that be 'dict_4_.txt?

Comment: That is a beautiful thing. I can reproduce your proposal. Of course the Spanish glyphs don't render properly in my BASH, but do when written to `output.txt` and opened with `NotePad++`. Gimme an hour to test on the longer strings.

Comment: @Jay Gray. Sorry, SO only.

Comment: ok - lemme think how best to do this. May trim the initial question, substitute your proposal and add data that is failing. May also submit a new question including progress-to-date. Do you have a preference?